Not a covering projection
My teacher told us that the application $D(0,1) \smallsetminus (\{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{2}\}) \rightarrow D(0,1) \smallsetminus \{0\}, z \mapsto z^2$ was not a covering projection (in the topological sense). I don't get why: is it just because the fiber over $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ only has one element and the others have two? Then it is just a matter of conventions (do fibers need to be all the same for each element in a fiber bundle or not). Or is there something I haven't seen?
Edit: I may have exchanged $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$.

There may be something you haven't seen: have you seen the definition of a covering projection? If so, did you check to verify that its definition is not satisfied by this example?

Tell me if I'm wrong. Let $p : z \mapsto z^2$. For $z = \frac{1}{4}$, with $r$ small enough, we have $p^{-1}(D(\frac{1}{4},r)) = D(\frac{1}{2},r) \smallsetminus {\frac{1}{2}} \sqcup D(-\frac{1}{2}, \sqrt{r})$. The problem is $p$ does not induce a homeomorphism from $D(\frac{1}{2},r) \smallsetminus {\frac{1}{2}}$ to $D(\frac{1}{4},r)$.

I can see you have the right idea of looking at $p^{-1}$ of some ball centered on $1/4$. However, it is unreasonable to expect that $p^{-1}$ of that ball is itself a union of balls. For example I'm sure you can do some calculations to convince yourself that your equation for $p^{-1}(D(\frac{1}{4},r))$ is wrong.

(Note: after the first = sign in my last comment, it is $\sqrt{r}$ and not $r$.) Ok, I was getting ahead of myself. Trying to correct: for $r$ small enough, $U = D(\frac{1}{4},r)$ does not meet $i\mathbb{R}^+$. Let $Log$ be a determination of the logarithm except on that half line. So $p^{-1}(U) = f(U) \smallsetminus {\frac{1}{2}} \sqcup -f(U)$ for $r$ small enough with $f : z \mapsto e^{\frac{1}{2} Log(p(z))}$. And I can use the same argument.

Irrespective of convention, the cardinality of the fiber of a covering projection (or, more generally, the homeomorphism type of the fiber of a bundle) is locally  constant on the base. This follows directly from the definition.
